# Extract id from from image path

Tags: regex

I am looking to extract an id from a url/filepath

The path can be:

`images/tJpwYL9baWgH56USKZwqTz7QM9g1_48x48.png` or `https://.../.../images/tJpwYL9baWgH56USKZwqTz7QM9g1_150x150.png`

I would like to extract the unique ids (in this case *tJpwYL9baWgH56USKZwqTz7QM9g1*)
So far I came up with the following expression:
`([^\/]+[_$])`
This includes however the _ , so I get *tJpwYL9baWgH56USKZwqTz7QM9g1_*

How can I do this and exclude the _?

Comment: Do all images always have dimensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```js
([^\/]+)_\d+x\d+\.png
[^\/]+(?=_\d+x\d+\.png)
```

See [this](https://regex101.com/r/VWhf8c/1) and [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VWhf8c/4). Details:

- `([^\/]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more chars other than `/`
- `_` - an underscore
- `\d+x\d+\.png` - one or more digits, `x`, one or more digits, `.png` string
- `(?=_\d+x\d+\.png)` - a positive lookahead that requires the pattern described above to appear immediately to the right of the current location (so, the text matched is not added to the match value)

Also, you might consider using simpler patterns like

```js
([^\W_]+)_
[^\W_]+(?=_)
```

See [this](https://regex101.com/r/VWhf8c/2) and [this pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/VWhf8c/3). The `[^\W_]+` pattern matches one or more letters or digits, `(?=_)` matches  a location that is immediately followed with a `_` char.

Comment: Albeit less efficient I would opt for `[^\/]+(?=_\d+x\d+\.png)` so that OP doesn't have to deal with capture groups. https://regex101.com/r/NOcfvv/1

Comment: Thanks a lot, you've just solved something in seconds that has kept me busy for way longer than I care to admit